# React Nested routing issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-component, react-routing

my router looks like the following,

```js
[
  { 
    path: '/',
    component: App,
    childRoutes: [
      { 
        path: 'dashboard', 
        getComponent: function(location, cb) {
            require.ensure([], function(require) {
              cb(null, require('../plugins/dashboard/index'))
            })
        },
        childRoutes: [
            {
                path: '/:id', 
                getComponent: function(location, cb) {
                    require.ensure([], function(require) {
                      cb(null, require('../plugins/dashboard/saved_dashboard'))
                    })
                }
            }
        ]
      },
      { 
        path: 'profile',
        getComponent: function(location, cb) {
            require.ensure([], function(require) {
              cb(null, require('../plugins/profile/index'))
            })
          }
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

And my menu component sample code looks like

```jsx
<ul id='menu'>
  <li>
    <Link to='dashboard'>dashboard</Link>
  </li>

  <li>
    <Link to='dashboard/mydashboard'>my dashboard</Link>
  </li>

  <li>
    <Link to='profile'>profile</Link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

the problem is when I click 'my dashboard' then it routes to

```
localhost/dashboard/mydashboard
```

from here if I click 'my dashboard' again it will routing to

```
localhost/dashboard/mydashboard/dashboard/mydashboard
```

and keep on going.

How to fix this issue? where I did the mistake?
or I have to do anything more in the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that is that `to` parameter of `Link` takes the absolute path and your paths are relative...

So to fix it, it should look like:

```jsx
<ul id='menu'>
  <li>
    <Link to='/dashboard'>dashboard</Link>
  </li>

  <li>
    <Link to='/dashboard/mydashboard'>my dashboard</Link>
  </li>

  <li>
    <Link to='/profile'>profile</Link>
  </li>
</ul>
```